# CakePHP multiple Sessions

Tags: php, cakephp

I am running a Cakephp 2.1 Application. One feature is as an admin you can login to lower level user accounts. This is done in a new window. At the moment when I try to access things in the first window they clash with the new session data.
I believe this is because everything is stored in the session cookie CAKEPHP.

If this is true then I would like to be able to create a new session cookie with a unique name that would be used by the new window. Please advise if this would work and how would be able to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions are cross-tab and cross-window. They are valid for the whole browser (if you do not have same sandbox or "invisible" mode for a single window anyway).

So just opening new windows and tabs will always overwrite all other sessions in that browser.
Since this is a browser limitation use different browsers if you need to be two roles at the same time.